# C# Add attachment to mailmessage without knowing the extension

Tags: c#, email, smtp, attachment, mailmessage

A system generates files with different extensions.
Those files have to be sent to an email address.

How can I put a file in an attachment without knowing the extension

For example "sample.xls" has to be added to the attachments but the application can also add "sample.txt", how do I handle that? I now have

```
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"M:/" + filename + ".xls");
```

I want something like this

```
attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@"M:/" + filename); // this didnt work
```

So that it sends any type of files. By the way, the filename isn't coming from code, but from a database without any extensions, so plain "sample" and it has to send the file with unknown extension, and it has to send it with the correct extension at the end.

Help will be really appreciated!

Comment: You are going to have to look for them and attach each one

Comment: What do you mean? Is there no easy solution for this?

Comment: use directory.getfiles with `filename + ".*"` to list all matching files and add each as an attachment

Comment: So if you have two files named "Sample" but both have different extensions, you want both to be added or only one?

Comment: No, there can be different files with different extensions but no duplicate filenames with different extensions. So "Sample.XLS" "Sample2.CSV" and "Sample3.TXT" Can be in the same directory, but have to be sent to other emails. But the mail part doesn't matter. I need to know how to attach files without knowing the extensions, but only the filename (sample,sample2,sample3);

Comment: @ Alex K. Do you have any noob-friendly links on how to do this?

Comment: What about serializing the file into binary and attaching the files as binary as opposed to a "file". Not sure whether it would work but perhaps a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `filename` is a file name only and does not contain other path components:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(@"M:\", filename + ".*"))
{
   yourMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(file));
}
```

If `filename` does contain sub-directories then

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(@"M:\", filename + ".*");
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath), Path.GetFileName(fullPath)))
{
   yourMailMessage.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(file));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this can help you(if you want to perform it by looping):

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("Directory of your file");
foreach (string s in files)
{
    if (s.Contains(@"FileName without extension"))
    {
        attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(s);
        mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);   // mailMessage is the name of message you want to attach the attachment
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error "The name 'Directory' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You should include System.IO;

Comment: Now it doesn't attach any files to the mail.

Comment: After attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(s); Write mailMessage.Attachments.Add(attachment);   // mailMessage is the mail message to which you want to attach the attachment..